# How to install powerlevel9k on mac

Tags: macos, fonts, themes, iterm2, powerline

Followed this guide to install `powerlevel9k` with `iterm2` on mac:

- https://gist.github.com/kevin-smets/8568070
- https://github.com/bhilburn/powerlevel9k/wiki/Install-Instructions#option-3-install-awesome-powerline-fonts

This is what I set into the `~/.zshrc` config file:

```
export ZSH="/Users/username/.oh-my-zsh"
ZSH_THEME="powerlevel9k/powerlevel9k"
POWERLEVEL9K_MODE='awesome-fontconfig'
source ~/.fonts/*.sh
```

But it seems that some icons didn't been found. What's wrong?

[the status now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yjvgb.png)

Comment: The important thins is: https://powerline.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation/linux.html#fonts-installation

Comment: This links is for Linux not for Mac Os x... `mv PowerlineSymbols.otf ~/.local/share/fonts/`???

Comment: even I am looking for the same. Did you get any help?

Answer (score 0):

iTerm2 → Preferences → Profiles → Text → Change Font to Hack Nerd Font

Don't forget to save the profile.